# Sum a field in buffer intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, buffer

I have looked and do not see this answered in any other discussions.

Purpose: Site suitability analysis for brewers spent grain processing facility

Method:  Locate intersecting buffers with greatest amount of spent grain - need field to sum barrels based on intersections (ex. Mountain Brewing Co. produces 3,000 barrels a year and Sierra Nevada produces 800,000 barrels a year - if the radii from the two breweries intersects the intersection would have a sum of 803,000 a year)

Using ArcMap 10.1, I have one shapefile that I have a 15 mile radius around each point (brewery).  I am trying to identify all intersecting buffers by summing a specific field.  I would eventually like for the intersections with the greatest number to be a 3D representation of barrels per year based on the sum field (I don't think I can do this in ArcMap 10.1 but need to transfer everything over to ArcScene, but I'm hoping not).

Comment: Could you go into more detail about what you have tried and what isn't working for you? This question looks like a homework question and that's generally frowned upon here. If you could provide additional information and what you have done, it may encourage others to help you.

Comment: I am doing this for an internship but will turn in as a project for class.  I already have a project I can turn in-- create buffers and identified sites at intersections-- but I wanted to make it even better-- it is outside the scope of what is covered in our class.  I have tried union buffers, intersect buffers converting buffer polygons to points to do a count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I would suggest:

1. Use the [Union tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) with your buffer feature class as the only input. This will effectively split each polygon at the boundaries of any others.
2. Run the [Find Identical tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000) on the output from the Union tool, using only `SHAPE` as the categorization field.
3. Join the output table from Find Identical back to the Union output's `OBJECTID` field by `IN_FID`.
4. Use the [Dissolve tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000) to dissolve by the joined `FEAT_SEQ` field (created by Find Identical), adding the sum of your barrel production field as a statistic.

(I wanted to test this out for you, but my ArcGIS installation keeps crashing when I run Find Identical on my test data...)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP! I can't believe you were able to do this without testing it in ArcGIS, amazing!